# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: In Java

Tags: java, recursion

I am a beginner in java and was learning recursion and I got the error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: ".
I thought I was doing something wrong so I copied the solution to test it n still got the same error .
The following code is the solution, I can't figure out why I am getting this error

```
public class Main {
    public static void permitutation(String str, String per) {
        if (str.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println(per);
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char current = str.charAt(i);
            String newstr = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1);
            permitutation(newstr, per + current);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        permitutation("abc", "");
    }
}
```

Comment: The only error I can see is that you have spelled "permutation" incorrectly.  But that isn't a programming error.

Comment: There are a few possibilities.  1) your file name is different from the class name Main.  2) you might have another Java file in your project that contains syntax errors.  2) the ide probably compiles a different project that has syntax errors.  I think it's most likely 1.

Comment: @ChengThao Thanks! It was because of 1). Maybe post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run your code on online compiler(you can check [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/3130a7c8-d3b5-483e-8a00-a6727a7e9f59)), thus the problem is not in your code, but maybe in your ide. In Eclipse you can

> Project -> clean

It will force clean your project and recompile the code.

Comment: i am using VS code